# is every polynomial function absolutely continuous?

Tags: measure-theory

> Is every polynomial function defined on a closed interval absolutely continuous ?

I think so because of fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Absolutely! :-)

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

- Polynomial functions are $C^1$.
- A $C^1$ function on a closed interval is Lipschitz.
- Lipschitz functions are absolutely continuous.

Comment: One should emphasize that $C^1$ means *continuously* differentiable, not just *differentiable*, otherwise the second fact would be wrong.